# Why do sh, zsh, and bash return zero when executing a zero byte file?

Tags: unix, sh, posix

Why can you can execute an empty file in bash, zsh, or sh and it will exit code 0 when an execve syscall with an empty file will exit ENOEXEC?

```
touch zero
chmod +x zero
./zero
echo $?
```

```
0
```

`execve` exit's -1 with `ENOEXEC Exec format error` so it isn't an operating systems behavior.

```
strace -f ./zero
execve("./zero", ["./zero"], [/* 53 vars */]) = -1 ENOEXEC (Exec format error)
write(2, "strace: exec: Exec format error\n", 32strace: exec: Exec format error
) = 32
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

sh also calls execve and gets -ENOEXEC but it proceeds to read 80 bytes of the file and exit zero.

```
strace -f sh -c "./zero"
...
execve("./zero", ["./zero"], [/* 52 vars */]) = -1 ENOEXEC (Exec format error)
open("./zero", O_RDONLY)                = 3
read(3, "", 80)                         = 0
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(0)
```

Comment: I found the relevent code in bash's source, but I'm still curious https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/3ba697465bc74fab513a26dea700cc82e9f4724e/execute_cmd.c#L5733-L5742

Comment: Seems like a special case of a shell script with no shebang, where the exec of the second shell is optimized out.

Comment: The code is fairly self-explanatory, `if (sample_len == 0) return (EXECUTION_SUCCESS);` Note the contents of the *comment* you link to: *"check to see ... if the contents of the first line (or up to 80 characters) are in the ASCII set.  If it's a text file, execute the contents as shell commands ..."* There is no *she-bang*, the file is empty, so `sample_len` will be zero.

Comment: It's self-explanatory just like `rand = 4` is. The _what_ is obvious, but _why_ is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `execve(2)` returns an error and sets `errno` to `ENOEXEC`, all shells will try to run an executable file as a shell script, ie. they will exec a shell with the file given as argument. An empty script will have a zero exit status (= success) [1].

What shell will they run exactly depends: `bash`, `ksh93` and `yash` will run the script themselves; `csh`, `dash`, `zsh` or `mksh` will always run it using `/bin/sh`.

This behavior is very old and predates the she-bang feature and the standardized executable file formats, and it's also required by the standard -- read the section 2. of [Command Search and Execution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_01_01) from the standard.

> `execve` exit's `-1` with `ENOEXEC` `Exec format error` so it isn't an operating systems behavior.

It is however [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execve.html) required behavior for the `execvp()` and `execlp()` library wrappers:

> In the cases where the other members of the exec family of
>        functions would fail and set `errno` to `ENOEXEC`, the `execlp()` and
>        `execvp()` functions shall execute a command interpreter and the
>        environment of the executed command shall be as if the process     invoked the `sh` utility using `execl()` as follows:
>
> ```
> execl(<shell path>, arg0, file, arg1, ..., (char *)0);`
> ```

[1] On older system `/bin/true` was a file consisting of just a copyright notice telling it's "unpublished proprietary source code of AT&T".